# Insertion in JDBC using ArrayList giving rows not in sequence

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I'm using the following code for getting values from `ArrayList` and adding into database. I'm using `PreparedStatement` and my database is Oracle.

```
ps = conn.prepareStatement("insert into Employee values(?,?,?,?,?)");
for (Employee e : elist) {
    ps.setInt(1, e.getEmployeeId());
    ps.setString(2, e.getEmployeeName());
    ps.setString(3, e.getGender());
    ps.setString(4, e.getDesignation());
    ps.setString(5, e.getEmail());
    added += ps.executeUpdate();
}
```

`elist` is an `ArrayList` of Employees.

here is the code for preparing the `ArrayList`:

```
Employee e1 = new Employee(1,"I","M","AS","abcd@gmail.com");
Employee e2 = new Employee(2,"A","M","RS","efgh@yahoo.in");
Employee e3 = new Employee(3,"S","F","SD","efgh@gmail.com");
Employee e4 = new Employee(4,"SS","F","SD","abcd@yahoo.in");
ArrayList<Employee> elist = new ArrayList<Employee>();
elist.add(e1);
elist.add(e2);
elist.add(e3);
elist.add(e4);
```

I've uploaded of the Employee table after insertion:

[image]

As you can see, the rows are not inserted as per the sequence of primary key i.e. Employee_Id values.I mean to say, when the data is inserted, the rows are normally expected to be in the sequence 1,2,3,4 . But it's not the case here.

I might have missed some very basic point in this, but I I've just begin with JDBC stuff.

Comment: What's the error? Btw, you are probably missing the column names in your INSERT statement.

Comment: Nothing. No error is there . I've attached the snapshot of resulting table. And regarding the column names, it also works without that.

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: If there is no error then why you asked question?

Comment: Rows in a relational database are ***not*** sorted. If you don't use an `order by` when retrieving the data the database is free to return them in any order it likes.

Comment: oh I'm sorry all. My question is incomplete. I'll just update it.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : so we can't just know what order is it stored in ?

Comment: There is no such thing as "*the order it is stored in*"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : Okay thanks for the info. But how can we, then, visualize it , if at all we can ?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : umm. How the data is stored ?

Answer (score 3):

SQL tables are unsorted sets. They have no intrinsic order. If you want to retrieve the values sorted by the employee id, you need to explicitly state it in your `order by` clause:

```sql
SELECT * FROM employee ORDER BY employee_id ASC
```